# tried to update hudson via dashboard and now it doesn't work (windows)

Tags: winapi, hudson

I get the following now in the output log.  I really wish I hadn't attempted to update the version.  What a hassle.

Can anyone diagnose the issue here?

Was trying to go from Hudson ver. 1.341 to the latest.  1.361?

All I see now when I go to the hudson url is:

> Please wait while Hudson is
>   restarting...
>
> Your browser will reload automatically
>   when Hudson is ready.

And then in the log file:

> Running from: C:\hudson\hudson.war
>   [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:33:54] -
>   Beginning extraction from war file
>   hudson home directory: C:\hudson
>   [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:33:56] - Error
>   during HTTP listener init or shutdown
>   java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized
>   Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:102)
>     at
>   winstone.HttpListener.run(HttpListener.java:116)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:33:56] - HTTP
>   Listener shutdown successfully
>   [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:33:56] -
>   Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10
>   running: controlPort=disabled
>   [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:33:56] - Error
>   during AJP13 listener init or shutdown
>   java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized
>   Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   winstone.ajp13.Ajp13Listener.run(Ajp13Listener.java:99)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:33:56] - AJP13
>   Listener shutdown successfully Running
>   from: C:\hudson\hudson.war [Winstone
>   2010/06/14 23:38:49] - Beginning
>   extraction from war file hudson home
>   directory: C:\hudson [Winstone
>   2010/06/14 23:38:51] - Winstone
>   Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running:
>   controlPort=disabled [Winstone
>   2010/06/14 23:38:51] - Error during
>   AJP13 listener init or shutdown
>   java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized
>   Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   winstone.ajp13.Ajp13Listener.run(Ajp13Listener.java:99)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:38:51] - AJP13
>   Listener shutdown successfully
>   [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:38:51] - Error
>   during HTTP listener init or shutdown
>   java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized
>   Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:102)
>     at
>   winstone.HttpListener.run(HttpListener.java:116)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>
> [Winstone 2010/06/14 23:38:51] - HTTP
>   Listener shutdown successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem upgrading from 1.361 to 1.362. Sometimes when Hudson is restarting its Windows service, the service stops but the Java process keeps running.

I also got no automatic upgrade, but closing down Hudson and replacing the `hudson.war` file with the downloaded one (which can be found in the same directory) helped.

Answer (score 10):

I've just had this problem.

Stopping and restarting the Windows service did not help.  I killed the `java` process manually, restarted the service and now it's back up and running.

Comment: This answer helped but I needed to install all plugins and set up admin account again.

Answer (score 2):

I had something similar, yesterday. The previous instance did not shut down correctly and you cant start the new instance since it can't open the port. Run `netstat-no` and look for the process that has your local Hudson port open. Kill that process and you will be able to start Hudson.

Alternatively, restart your server. That helps too.

Comment: Thanks.  I resarted my OS and it seemed to fix the problem.  However, I am still running the older version of hudson.  I can't seem to upgrade...

Comment: how did you try to update the server? Is your old system installed under C:\hudson\? Are there problems with the file permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue and restarting the system fixed it.